# how to convert W^2/Hz to dB/Hz?

Tags: power-spectral-density

I have power spectral density  data in W^2/Hz?  I want power spectral density  in dB/Hz. How to convert W^2/Hz to dB/Hz?
I saw some answers. But I did't understand. Please explain

Comment: Hi! We do expect a bit of own research. In this case, reading Wikipedia on what a decibel is would have shown you that it's not per se a unit of power.

Answer (score 2):

**dB** is not a physical unit per se. It is a logarithmic measure in relation to a certain physical quantity. The reference point is usually given together with **dB**.

The unit of a PSD is usually **W/Hz**. I'm not sure, what **W²/Hz** is, but it is *not* a PSD.
Depending on the levels involved, the usual **dB** units for a PSD are **dBm/Hz** or **dBW/Hz**, so either **1 mW** or **1 W** are used as reference point.

The conversion between linear and dB scale for a power measure is given by $10\log\frac{p_1}{p_r}$ with $p_1$ being the measure to convert and $p_r$ the reference point. So for converting a value of, say, **3W/Hz** to **dBm** we calculate

$$3\text{W/Hz}=10\log\left(\frac{3\text{W}}{1\text{mW}}\right)\text{dBm/Hz} = 10\log\left(3000\right)\text{dBm/Hz} = 34.8\text{dBm/Hz}$$